# Induction proof of the identity $\cos x+\cos(2x)+\cdots+\cos (nx) = \frac{\sin(\frac{nx}{2})\cos\frac{(n+1)x}{2}}{\sin(\frac{x}{2})}$

Tags: trigonometry, summation, induction

> Prove that:$$\cos x+\cos(2x)+\cdots+\cos (nx)=\frac{\sin(\frac{nx}{2})\cos\frac{(n+1)x}{2}}{\sin(\frac{x}{2})}.\ (1)$$

**My attempt:**$$\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\sum_{k=1}^{n}\cos{(kx)}$$$$=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\cos{(kx)} $$ (Applying $\sin x\cos y =\frac{1}{2}\left[\sin(x+y)+\sin(x-y)\right]$)
$$=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2}\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}-kx\right)+\frac{1}{2}\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}+kx\right).$$**Multiplying** $(1)$ by $\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$ ,**gives**: $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\cos(kx)=\sin\left(\frac{nx}{2}\right)\cos{\frac{(n+1)x}{2}}$$ $$\Leftrightarrow\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left[\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}-kx\right)+\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}+kx\right)\right]=\sin\left(-\frac{x}{2}\right)+\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}+nx\right).$$**Then, by induction on $n$ and using** $(\sin x\sin y)$ **and** $(\sin x +\sin y)$ **formulas, I end in here**:  $$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\cos(kx)=\left[2\sin\left(\frac{nx}{2}\right)\cos\frac{(n+1)x}{2}\right]+\left[2\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\cos(n+1)x\right].$$ Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Do you want a proof using induction or only a proof?

Comment: I'm a first grader, so induction only :)

Comment: But if there is no induction proof, then any proof would be appreciated

Comment: Non-inductive proofs (including my [trigonograph](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1607308/409)) are given in this question: ["How can we sum up $\sin$ and $\cos$ series when the angles are in arithmetic progression?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17966/how-can-we-sum-up-sin-and-cos-series-when-the-angles-are-in-arithmetic-pro). I believe this question has arisen on this site a few other times as well, perhaps receiving an inductive proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the induction step: it comes down to proving
\begin{gather*}\frac{\sin \dfrac{nx}{2} \cos\dfrac{(n+1)x}{2}}{\sin\dfrac{x}{2}}+\cos(n+1)x=\frac{\sin\dfrac{(n+1)x}{2}\cos\dfrac{(n+2)x}{2}}{\sin(\dfrac{x}{2})}\\
\text{or}\qquad\sin\dfrac{nx}{2}\cos\dfrac{(n+1)x}{2}+\sin\dfrac{x}{2}\cos(n+1)x=\sin\dfrac{(n+1)x}{2} \cos\dfrac{(n+2)x}{2}
\end{gather*}
Now use the linearisation formulae:
\begin{cases}\displaystyle
\sin\frac{nx}{2}\cos\frac{(n+1)x}{2}=\tfrac12\biggl(\sin\frac{(2n+1)x}{2}-\sin\frac x2\biggr),\\[1ex]
\sin\dfrac{x}{2}\cos(n+1)x=\frac12\biggl(\sin\dfrac{(2n+3)x}{2}-\sin\dfrac{(2n+1)x}{2}\biggr),
\end{cases}
whence the l.h.s. is
$$\frac12\biggl(\sin\dfrac{(2n+3)x}{2}-\sin\frac x2\biggr)=\sin\frac{(n+1)x}2\,\cos\frac{(n+2)x}2$$
by the factorisation formula: $\;\sin p-\sin q=2\sin\dfrac{p-q}2\cos\dfrac{p+q}2$.

Comment: Since when $$\sin\frac{nx}{2}\cos\frac{(n+1)x}{2}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sin\frac{(2n+1)x}{2}- \sin\frac{x}{2}\right)$$ and $$\sin\frac{x}{2}\cos(n+1)x=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sin\frac{(2n+3)x}{2}-\sin\frac{(2n+1)x}{2}\right)$$ ?

Comment: Apply the linearisation formula: $\; \sin a \cos b=\frac12\bigl(\sin(a+b)+\sin(a-b)\bigr)$.

Comment: Well, it was easier than I thought

Comment: It's easier  with Euler's formulae and complex numbers, though. With trigonometry you have to know a little more than basic formulae. Actually I think the minimal background in trigonometry is ~ 20 formulae ( not counting this one, which everyone  should know).

Answer (score 0):

You want to show that
$$
\frac{\sin\frac{nx}{2}\cos\frac{(n+1)x}{2}}{\sin\frac{x}{2}}
+\cos((n+1)x)=
\frac{\sin\frac{(n+1)x}{2}\cos\frac{(n+2)x}{2}}{\sin\frac{x}{2}}
$$
which is the same as
$$
\sin\frac{nx}{2}\cos\frac{(n+1)x}{2}+\sin\frac{x}{2}\cos((n+1)x)=
\sin\frac{(n+1)x}{2}\cos\frac{(n+2)x}{2}
$$
Set $s=nx/2$ and $t=x/2$; the relation becomes, after multiplying by $2$ for later applying the product to sum formulas,
$$
2\sin s\cos(s+t)+2\sin t\cos(2s+2t)=2\sin(s+t)\cos(s+2t)
$$
Recall
$$
2\sin\alpha\cos\beta=\sin(\alpha+\beta)+\sin(\alpha-\beta)
$$
so the left-hand side becomes
$$
\sin(2s+t)+\sin(-t)+\sin(2s+3t)+\sin(-2s-t)=
\sin(2s+3t)-\sin t
$$
The right-hand side becomes
$$
\sin(2s+3t)+\sin(-t)=\sin(2s+3t)-\sin t
$$