# How to prove with matematical induction: $\cos1 + \cos 2 + \cdots + \cos n = -\frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sin(n+\frac{1}{2})}{2\sin\frac{1}{2}}$

Tags: trigonometry, induction

I'm having truble calculating right side of this equation

$$\cos1 + \cos 2 + \cdots + \cos n = -\frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sin(n+\frac{1}{2})}{2\sin\frac{1}{2}}$$ for $n = 1$.

I've managed to reach that $$cos1 = -\frac{1}{2} + \frac{\cos^2 1 -\cos1 -\sin^2 1}{2(1-\cos1)}$$

Can i get any tips on how to solve this equation? (If it's even correct at this point).

Thanks.

Comment: Also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1973736/prove-that-cos-alpha-cos2-alpha-cdots-cos-n-alpha-frac12-left-frac-s?rq=1

Comment: How popular is this question?

Comment: this is actually a bit different, as it asks to use induction

Comment: Multiply both sides by $2\sin\frac{1}{2}$ in order to turn the LHS into a telescopic series, due to $$2\cos(n)\sin\frac{1}{2} = \sin\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)-\sin\left(n-\frac{1}{2}\right)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $n=1$, the right-hand side is
$$
-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sin(3/2)}{2\sin(1/2)}
$$
Let $\alpha=1/2$ for simplicity; you get
$$
-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sin3\alpha}{2\sin\alpha}
=
-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{3\sin\alpha-4\sin^3\alpha}{2\sin\alpha}=
\frac{-1+3-4\sin^2\alpha}{2}=1-2\sin^2\alpha=\cos2\alpha=\cos1
$$

Answer (score 1):

Something went wrong in your computation for $n=1$, which is going to conclude in $cos1=-1-cos1$.
It shall go like this:
$$
\begin{gathered}
   - \frac{1}
{2} + \frac{{\sin \left( {1 + 1/2} \right)}}
{{2\sin \left( {1/2} \right)}} = \frac{1}
{2}\left( {\frac{{\sin \left( 1 \right)\cos \left( {1/2} \right) + \cos \left( 1 \right)\sin \left( {1/2} \right)}}
{{\sin \left( {1/2} \right)}} - 1} \right) =  \hfill \\
   = \frac{1}
{2}\left( {\frac{{\sin \left( 1 \right)\cos \left( {1/2} \right) + \left( {\cos \left( 1 \right) - 1} \right)\sin \left( {1/2} \right)}}
{{\sin \left( {1/2} \right)}}} \right) =  \hfill \\
   = \frac{1}
{2}\left( {\frac{{2\sin \left( {1/2} \right)\cos ^{\,2} \left( {1/2} \right) + \left( {2\cos ^{\,2} \left( {1/2} \right) - 2} \right)\sin \left( {1/2} \right)}}
{{\sin \left( {1/2} \right)}}} \right) =  \hfill \\
   = \frac{1}
{2}\left( {2\cos ^{\,2} \left( {1/2} \right) + \left( {2\cos ^{\,2} \left( {1/2} \right) - 2} \right)} \right) = \left( {2\cos ^{\,2} \left( {1/2} \right) - 1} \right) = \cos 1 \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
$$
After that, we have:
$$
\begin{gathered}
  \cos 1 + \cos 2 + \; \cdots \; + \cos n + \cos (n + 1) =  \hfill \\
   =  - \frac{1}
{2} + \frac{{\sin \left( {n + 1/2} \right)}}
{{2\sin \left( {1/2} \right)}} + \cos (n + 1) =  \hfill \\
   = \frac{1}
{2}\left( {\frac{{\sin \left( {n + 1/2} \right)}}
{{\sin \left( {1/2} \right)}} - 1 + 2\cos (n + 1)} \right) =  \hfill \\
   = \frac{1}
{2}\left( {\frac{{\sin \left( {n + 1/2} \right) - \sin \left( {1/2} \right) + 2\cos (n + 1)\sin \left( {1/2} \right)}}
{{\sin \left( {1/2} \right)}}} \right) =  \hfill \\
   = \frac{1}
{2}\left( {\frac{{\sin \left( {n + 1} \right)\cos \left( {1/2} \right) + \cos \left( {n + 1} \right)\sin \left( {1/2} \right) - \sin \left( {1/2} \right)}}
{{\sin \left( {1/2} \right)}}} \right) =  \hfill \\
   = \frac{1}
{2}\left( {\frac{{\sin \left( {n + 1 + 1/2} \right) - \sin \left( {1/2} \right)}}
{{\sin \left( {1/2} \right)}}} \right) =  - \frac{1}
{2} + \frac{{\sin \left( {n + 1 + 1/2} \right)}}
{{\sin \left( {1/2} \right)}} \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
$$
which is the demonstration you are looking for.